# Covering Index can't optimize the limit query in mysql8.0

Tags: java, mysql, sql, indexing

In **< High Performance Mysql >**, it uses covering index to optimize limit query like this. I used the **sakila** database downloaded from MySQL official web. Here is the query：

```
SELECT a.film_id, a.description 
  from sakila.film a 
  inner join (
    select film_id 
      from sakila.film b 
      order by title limit 50,5
  ) as lim 
  USING(film_id)
```

But I use **explain** to analyze the process. It looks like this.[image]

In the third line, it shows that it still scans all the 1000 rows. 
Then I tested the subquery`select film_id from sakila.film b order by title limit 50,5`, the explain log like this [image: log1].

In my opnion, the third line in the first log should be like the second log, and I don't know how to explain the first 2 rows
 in first log, why the rows are 55 and 1, I think maybe they should be 5 and 5. This is the MySQL official demo.  I guess it is because of the version of the mysql.

I update my mysql to the 8.0.11.0, it becames a little more normal like this [image]

I tested same dataset int mysql8.0 and mysql5.6, in mysql5.6 it only need 0.2s to  retrieve data, but in mysql8.0 it need 1s to do it. What is different in them? And
The first row is still 905 rather than 5.  Can somebody tell me the reason and why the first row is 905, the second row is 1?

Comment: Please show the explain plan. MySQL is not that great when it comes to join with subqueries. It tends to run it again for every main row.

Comment: I guess it is because of the version of the mysql. I tested it on 5.7.2 and 5.5.0. It had 3 kinds of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXPLAIN` is notorious for ignoring `LIMIT` values.

Here's a better way to get a feel for what is going on:

```
 FLUSH STATUS;
 SELECT ...;
 SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Using a similar query (on 5.6) on some data I have...

```
SELECT  city, province, population
    FROM  canada AS a
    JOIN ( SELECT  id
            FROM  canada
            ORDER BY  city
            LIMIT  300,20    -- I used bigger numbers
         ) AS x USING(id);
```

(The table has 5484 rows.)

```
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 4     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 21    |  -- about 20
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 319   |  -- about 300+20 (OFFSET+LIMIT)
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 21    |  -- about 20
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 20    |  -- 20  (the 'derived' table)
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  320 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | eq_ref | id            | id      | 4       | x.id |    1 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | canada     | index  | NULL          | city_id | 771     | NULL | 5484 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

So...  No table scan.  The `OFFSET` is included only in the derived table.

The `Using index` in your `EXPLAIN` (and mine) confirms the use of a "covering index".

(I think...)  In older versions, `EXPLAIN` would actually evaluate any Derived table; 8.0 avoids that.  This could partially explain why *Explain* changed in your two outputs.